# XMLHttpRequest response access denied despite same-origin

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

*response is JSON*

---

**Edge**: sometimes inserts response property value into DOM briefly then removes it, sometimes logs error "SCRIPT5: access denied" (indicating CORS), response fully accessible from Debugger, request shown in network tab

**Chrome**: response empty string, request not shown in network tab, no console message

**Firefox**: console error 'response "malformed JSON"' on breakpoint line using response in JSON.parse(), thus before usage, request not shown in network tab, Firebug and integrated

---

**JS** (current browsers only):

```
var session = "";
var request;
function checkLogin()
{
    if(request.readyState > 3)
    {
        var response = JSON.parse(request.response);
        if(verify(response))  // verify inserts argument property "error" in DOM on error via innerHTML on element
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
function login()
{
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = checkLogin;
    request.open("GET", "authenticateUser.php?user=" + document.getElementById("user").value + "&credential="+md5(document.getElementById("password").value));
    request.send();
}
```

---

Edge request from network tab:

```
Anforderungs-URL: http://*MYDOMAIN*/authenticateUser.php?user=df&credential=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
Anforderungsmethode: GET
Statuscode: 200 / OK
 - Anforderungsheader
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: de-DE, de; q=0.8, en-US; q=0.5, en; q=0.3
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: *MYDOMAIN*
Referer: http://*MYDOMAIN*/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586
 - Antwortheader
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 65
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sat, 21 Nov 2015 07:42:17 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=94
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.29
```

---

response:

```
{"success":false,"error":"authentication failed or unauthorised"}
```

---

What is going to make my phps' response be usable in JS code (in Chrome and Firefox) and its properties value be insertable into the DOM?

Comment: console.log the request.response before you try to parse it and verify it is valid JSON

Comment: the console.log appears exactly as written under "response" above. I believe it is valid JSON. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: something's odd: even Charles doesn't display network traffic for the xhr. But it's a fresh response (in Edge). Windows Task Manager Performance Tab shows the data being transmitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`login()` is the handler of `onsubmit`. I didn't `return false`; thus the form from which the user and pw came from - having no action - submitted to its own page and made the browser reload the page: cancelling the request in Chrome and Ff. Only Edge let the equal page JS handle the repsonse from the former loads request - until it was to be inserted.

Took me 6 hours and a detour through JSONP and Charles then listing the network traffic from Chrome where the page itself appeared after the request thus letting me have the idea that the page "reloaded" and finally remembering onsubmits handler cancels the submit with return false and else submits leading to a load of the action (or self if none) which is what happened here.